# Bootstrap: align the content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i'm working on this website http://ba-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/antonio2/ (**Bootstrap**)

As you can see the content is not perfectly aligned to the first slider. What i need is to perfectly align it (see the screenshot). I provide  you the HTML code too:

[image]

HTML:

```
        <!-- Start 3 columns -->  
    <div class="row fluid bg" style="background-image: url('img/bg_section.png'); background-size: 100%; height: 666px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1 class="headline home">ARCHITEKTUR</h1>
                <h2 class="subtitle home">Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh.</h2>
                <p class="text home">Vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum.</p>
            </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1 class="headline home">LAGE</h1>
                <h2 class="subtitle home">Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh.</h2>
                <p class="text home">Vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1 class="headline home">WOHNUNGEN</h1>
                <h2 class="subtitle home">Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh.</h2>
                <p class="text home">Vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 picture">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/place.jpg" />
            <h2 class="text-under-picture">Lorem Ipsum. <strong>Proin</strong> gravida nibh vel<strong><br>velit</strong> auctor aliquet. Lorem <strong>Ipsum</strong></h2>    
            </div>

        </div>  
    </div>
   <!-- End 3 Columns -->
```

Comment: wrap it with a `container` for your needed width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `padding` on `.bg`, you can achieve the effect:

```
.row.fluid.bg {
    margin-bottom: 500px;
    padding: 0 50px;   /* this is new - adjust the 50px if you want*/
}
```

(look at `main.css` line 92)

The good thing about this method is, that the inside columns adopting the new size.

---

As a little add-on, you could try to add

```
.navbar {
    margin-left: 64px;
    margin-right: 64px;
}
```

Comment: This work perfectly! Another question: can i align the slider to the secon background picures? I mean align to this background-image: url('img/bg_section.png');

Comment: Sure! Just add `margin-left: 0px;` and `margin-right: 0px;` to `.row.fluid.bg`. You can adjust these values like you need them (lower means wider content).

Comment: Have you considered to use pseudo elements for the zig zag effect?